# Branch Offset out of Range. ARM Assembly program for printing prime numbers upto N, where N is the user input

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

My main source file :

```
L0  LDR R0, =prompt
    BL WriteString  ;print prompt
    BL ReadInt      ;R0 = n
    CMP R0, #0
    BGE L1 
    LDR R0, =res0       ; invalid input
    BL  WriteString
    B   L0
    
L1  MOV R1, #2
L2  UDIV    R2, R0, R1
    MLS R2, R1, R2, R0
    CBZ R2, L3
    BL WriteInt
    ADD R1, #1
    CMP R1, R0
    BLT L2

L3  SUB R0, #1
    CBZ R0, L0    ;Error: A1176E: Branch offset 0xFFFFFFC8 out of range.  
    B   L1

prompt  DCB "Enter a positive integer: ", 0
res0    DCB 13, 10, "Invalid input", 13, 10, 0
    ALIGN
    END
```

I am also having issues breaking out of the loop at L2. Any advice to improve this code into working order would be appreciated.

Comment: Surprisingly, google didn't find any duplicates for this when searching on `site:stackoverflow.com cbz branch backwards` or similar.  I thought this would have come up at least once before.

Answer (score 7):

This ARM [developer page](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0489/c/arm-and-thumb-instructions/branch-and-control-instructions/cbz-and-cbnz) says

> **CBZ and CBNZ**
>
> <sup>**Restrictions**</sup>
>
> The branch destination must be within 4 to 130 bytes after the instruction and in the same execution state.

You are trying to branch backwards by 56 bytes.

---

You probably want to use `subs r0, #1` and branch on flags; `beq` is just as compact as `cbz` but *can* branch backwards.

Also, `subs` and `adds` are available as 16-bit thumb instructions, unlike `sub` and `add` which only have 32-bit encodings, so you normally want that anyway.